# Find out what is OPA getting as request from api-server?

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent

We have OPA installed in our Kubernetes cluster. Not Gatekeeper. The "original" OPA...

**I don't understand how I can look at what OPA is receiving as input request from the API-server ?**
=> If I knew exactly what the payload looks like then writing the Rego would be simple.

I tried to use `-v=8` option in `kubectl` to see the request and response from api-server like so:

```
$ kubectl get pod -v=8
...
GET https://xxxx.k8s.ovh.net/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500
...
Request Headers: Accept: application/json;as=Table;v=v1;g=meta.k8s.io,application/json;as=Table;v=v1beta1;g=meta.k8s.io,application/json
...
Response Body: {"kind":"Table","apiVersion":"meta.k8s.io/v1","metadata":{"resourceVersion":"37801112226"},"columnDefinitions":[{"name":"Name","type":"string","format":"name","description":"Name must be unique within a namespace. Is required when creating resources, although some resources may allow a client to request the generation of an appropriate name automatically. Name is primarily intended for creation idempotence and configuration definition. Cannot be updated. More info: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/identifiers#names","priority":0},{"name":"Ready","type":"string","format":"","description":"The aggregate readiness state of this pod for accepting traffic.","priority":0},{"name":"Status","type":"string","format":"","description":"The aggregate status of the containers in this pod.","priority":0},{"name":"Restarts","type":"string","format":"","description":"The number of times the containers in this pod have been restarted and when the last container in this pod has restarted.","priority":0},{"name":"Age","type [truncated 4024 chars]
```

Unfortunatly the above JSON payload doesn't match what I see in the different tutorials.

*How is anybody able to write OPA rules for Kubernetes ???*
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Run the OPA server with debug level logging:

  `opa run --server --log-level debug ...`

  This is obviously very noisy, so beware.
- Run the server with [decision logging](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management-decision-logs/) enabled. This is almost always preferable, and allows you to either dump decisions (including input data) to console, or for production deployments, to a remote server aggregating the logs. The decision logging system is really the native way of doing this, and comes with a bunch of features, like masking of sensitive data, etc.. but if you just want something printed to the console, you can run OPA like:

  `opa run --server --set decision_logs.console=true ...`